# Lucene performance: Transferring fields data from one index to another

Tags: java, search, lucene

In short, I am in need to exchange the mapping of multiple field and values from one Index to the resulting Index.

The following is the scenario.

**Index 1** Structure
[Field => Values] [Stored]

```
Doc 1    
keys => keyword1;    
Ids => id1, id1, id2, id3, id7, id11, etc.. 

Doc 2    
keys => keyword2;    
Ids => id3, id11, etc..
```

**Index 2** Structure
[Field => Values] [Stored]

```
Doc 1    
ids => id1    
keys => keyword1, keyword1

Doc 3    
ids => id3    
keys => keyword1, keyword2, etc..
```

Please note that the keys<->ids **mapping is reversed** in the resulting Index.

What do you think the most effective way to accomplish this in terms of time complexity? ..

The only way I could think of is that..

```
1) index1Reader.terms();    
2) Process only terms belonging to "Ids" field    
3) For each term, get TermDocs    
4) For each doc, load it, get "keys" field info    
5) Create a new Lucene Doc, add 'Id', multi Keys, write it to index2.     
6) Go to step 2.
```

Since the fields are stored, I'm sure that there are multiple ways of doing it.

Please guide me with any performance techniques. **Even the slightest improvement** will have a huge impact in my scenario considering that the Index1 size is ~ 6GB.

Total no. of unique keywords: 18 million;
Total no. of unique ids: 0.9 million

Interesting **UPDATE**

**Optimization 1**

- While adding a new doc, instead of creating multiple duplicate 'Field' objects, creating a single StringBuffer with " " delimiter, and then adding entire as a single Field seems to have up to 25% improvement.

**UPDATE 2: Code**

```
    public void go() throws IOException, ParseException {
    String id = null;
    int counter = 0;
    while ((id = getNextId()) != null) { // this method is not taking time..
        System.out.println("Node id: " + id);
        updateIndex2DataForId(id);
        if(++counter > 10){
            break;
        }
    }
    index2Writer.close();
}

private void updateIndex2DataForId(String id) throws ParseException, IOException {
    // Get all terms containing the node id
    TermDocs termDocs = index1Reader.termDocs(new Term("id", id));
    // Iterate
    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.add(new Field("id", id, Store.YES, Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
    int docId = -1;        
    while (termDocs.next()) {
        docId = termDocs.doc();
        doc.add(getKeyDataAsField(docId, Store.YES, Index.NOT_ANALYZED));            
    }
    index2Writer.addDocument(doc);
}

private Field getKeyDataAsField(int docId, Store storeOption, Index indexOption) throws CorruptIndexException,
        IOException {
    Document doc = index1Reader.document(docId, fieldSelector); // fieldSel has "key"
    Field f = new Field("key", doc.get("key"), storeOption, indexOption);
    return f;
}
```

Comment: is this just a one time thing?  my guess would be that the time spent thinking about it would be greater than the amount of time saved in optimizations...  6gb is a big index but lucene can handle this stuff pretty quickly... have you done a brute force test to see how long it would take?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Even though it is a one-time thing, I might have to do it a couple of times before my deadline. So, thinking of perf impr. 
Yeah, I've tried above approach, time consumption is a bit disappointing. It is taking multiple seconds(2-5+) for each doc. 
Total no. of expected docs is up to a million.

Comment: What is taking so long have you profiled that?

Comment: Not sure yet, loading the Document might be a candidate culprit.. I should load only 'keyword' in which case I can avoid loading the very lengthy 'ids' field..

Comment: @phani wow! multiple seconds per document is pretty outrageous...  should not be this slow. can you post some of the code you are using so we can take a look at it?

Comment: @LelandRichardson Thanks for the reply. I've updated the code, please take a look. I think, it is the huge length (like 100k) of termDocs that's taking the time.

Comment: @phani thanks for posting the code.  based on your code you are doing all of the typical performance hiccups (that i know of at least) correctly...  how much RAM does the machine you are running this on have? termdocs could take awhile if the machine isn't able to load the whole index into RAM...

Comment: also something to note: provided you do everything thread-safe, you could parallelize everything and open up a threadpool where you are one for each id...

Comment: @LelandRichardson Thanks a lot for your suggestions, RAM is properly allotted like 3GB for the program. Yeah, Multithreading is surely a savior once we end up with no more framework related optimizations..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usage of FieldCache worked like a charm... But, we need to allot more and more RAM to accommodate all the fields on the heap.

I've updated the above updateIndex2DataForId() with the following snippet..

```
private void updateIndex2DataForId(String id) throws ParseException, IOException {
    // Get all terms containing the node id
    TermDocs termDocs = index1Reader.termDocs(new Term("id", id));
    // Iterate
    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.add(new Field("id", id, Store.YES, Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
    int docId = -1;
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while (termDocs.next()) {
        docId = termDocs.doc();
        buffer .append(keys[docId] + " "); // keys[] is pre-populated using FieldCache                 
    }
    doc.add(new Field("id", buffer.trim().toString(), Store.YES, Index.ANALYZED));   
    index2Writer.addDocument(doc);
}

String[] keys = FieldCache.DEFAULT.getStrings(index1Reader, "keywords");
```

It made everything faster, I cannot tell you the exact metrics but I must say very substantial.

Now the program is completing in a bit of reasonable time. Anyways, further guidance is highly appreciated.

Comment: Doh. Didn't even think about using the fieldcache...  and yeah I would imagine with only 3gb you will need a bit more to get this screaming along.